# Selection of tuples from 1 rdd based on other rdd

Tags: apache-spark

I am having 2 rdds as below

```
rdd1 =[(string),(string),list(string)]
rdd as rdd2 =[(string)]
```

Here the rdd2  is  subset from list(string) of rdd1. I have to select only those tuples from rdd1 which has elements of rdd2 in rdd1's list(string).
What can be the method to get this result.  e.g.

```
rdd1 =[(a,x,(p,q,r)), (b,y,(q,s,t)),(c,z,(o,p,q,n,m)]

rdd2= [p,n]
```

for this result should  select first and last tuple from rdd1 so result

```
rdd3 = [a,x,(p,q,r)), (c,z,(o,p,q,n,m)]
```

Comment: can you please suggest the solution/ approach for this

Comment: This is an interesting problem, I am validating my solution and will share if it works.

Comment: it will be better if you share exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: the intention is to select all the  2nd  fields  from  rdd3. this situation i got while parsing  unstructured data from a hadoop file in spark. so need help from experts  for this

Comment: how is rdd1 is created in first place?

Comment: rdd1 was created by parsing the file in spark using wholefile input format. in spark i  did text parsing using filter operations and created rdd1 from hadoop rdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> rdd1 = sc.parallelize([
... ("a", "x", ("p", "q", "r")), ("b", "y", ("q", "s", "t")), ("c", "z", ("o", "p", "q", "n" ,"m"))
... ])
>>> rdd2 = sc.parallelize(["p", "n"])
>>> rdd1.cartesian(rdd2) \
...     .filter(lambda ((_1, _2, xs), x): x in xs) \
...     .map(lambda x: x[0]) \
...     .distinct()
```

It is expensive so be careful.